# Mule SQSConnectorException: Invalid binary character in xml payload - Encrypting payload

Tags: mule, amazon-sqs

I am trying to send an xml payload over SQS using Mule.

I have no issues sending the xml payload to SQS in plain text HOWEVER when my requirement changed to encrypt the payload using pgp encryption Amazon threw me back an error (SQSConnectorException) about invalid binary characters.

How can I encrypt the my xml payload in an Amazon friendly way?

My sqs configuration looks like this at the moment...

```
    <sqs:send-message config-ref="amazonSQSConfiguration" doc:name="Push To Trx Hist Queue" queueUrl="${aws.sqs.baseUrl}/${aws.sqs.trx.hist.queue.name}">
        <sqs:message messageBody="#[payload]" />
    </sqs:send-message>
```

Comment: SQS is a text (utf-8) transport, so it won't accept arbitrary binary data.  Are you familiar with the PGP/GPG concept of [ASCII Armor](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-to-text_encoding)? That sounds like what you need.  Which library are you using for to handle PGP?  Also, how large are your messages?  Encoding PGP payload (or any binary data) in an SQS-friendly way will typically reduce the available max message size from ~256k to ~192k because only 6 of the theoretical 8 bits per byte will be used to encode data.

Comment: my email messages are small. 600 bytes. I do not know about ascii Armour but I will have a look. We are using org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPException for pgp encryption.

Comment: I think an `ArmoredOutputStream` is what you are looking for. This should result in a text-transport-friendly representation of your encrypted content, so you should have no issue with SQS.  It may or may not require changes on the receive side -- possibly the armored representation may be automatically detected -- I don't know.  I've worked with SQS and I've worked with PGP, but I'm not well-versed in Java.  When you figure out how to do it, please post an answer here for the benefit of future visitors.